# Why Canvas implementation is faster than Pixi.JS one?

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

I'm writing a 2D game engine. To check performance I was drawing 1000 objects with 3 children each. Only the children are drawn, and the structure looks like this:

`var object = {
  x:,
  y:,
  length:,
  children: [
    /* this repeats three times */
  ]
};`

Not using path caching my implementation of drawing any object looks like this:

```
save();

translate(object.x, object.y);
rotate(object.rotation);

beginPath();
moveTo(0, 0);
lineTo(object.length / 8, -object.length / 8);
lineTo(object.length, 0);
lineTo(object.length / 8, object.length / 8);
stroke();

for (child in children) {
  // repeat the same for each child
}

restore();
```

It gets ~25FPS with 500 objects (1500 total draws with children). I tried PIXI.js to see if WebGL would be faster. I used `PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer` for objects and `PIXI.Graphics` for each children (calling the `moveTo...lineTo` block once on each of them at init time). It couldn't get above 20FPS.

Did I did something wrong or is there some magic Canvas performance boost over WebGL when drawing paths? It was on Chrome 33.0.1750.149 on Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

Comment: Isn't this really a pixi.js question not a WebGL question? There's plenty of examples of WebGL drawing up to a million paths. If pixi.js can't do it that's arguably a pixi.js issue, not a WebGL issue.

Comment: @gman right, removed the WebGL tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm probably you've already fixed the issue considering the date this question was posted.

It's likely you user `Canvas Renderer` instead of `WebGL` one.

You can force it to have `WebGL Renderer` like below

```
var renderer = new PIXI.WebGLRenderer(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

instead of

```
var renderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
// can be either Canvas or WebGL
```